# How to process a regular expression after being evaluated (sed)

Tags: regex, bash, shell, ksh

I need to replace each character of a regular expression, **once evaluated**, with each character plus the @ symbol.

For example:

If the regular expression is:   `POS[AB]`

and the input text is:          `POSA_____POSB`

I want to get this result:      `P@O@S@A@_____P@O@S@B@`

Please, using **sed** or **awk**.

I have tried this:

```
$ echo "POSA_____POSB" | sed "s/POS[AB]/&@/g"

POSA@_____POSB@

$ echo "POSA_____POSB" | sed "s/./&@/g"

P@O@S@A@_@_@_@_@_@P@O@S@B@
```

But what I need is:

```
P@O@S@A@_____P@O@S@B@
```

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Octavio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the resuce!

```
perl -pe 's/(POS[AB])/$1 =~ s:(.):$1@:gr/ge'
```

The `/e` interprets the replacement as code, and it contains another substitution which replaces each character with itself plus `@`.

In ancient Perls before 5.14 (i.e. without the `/r` modifier), you need to use a bit more complex

```
perl -pe 's/(POS[AB])/$x = $1; $x =~ s:(.):$1@:g; $x/ge'
```

Comment: This is the only suggestion (so far) that correctly limits the addition of "@" to regex matches. For example, `echo "POSA____OOPS____POSB" | perl -pe 's/(POS[AB])/$1 =~ s:(.):$1@:gr/ge'` prints "P@O@S@A@____OOPS____P@O@S@B@" (as it should).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I can not get it to work, it gives me the following error: $ echo "POSA_____POSB" | perl -pe 's/(POS[AB])/$1 =~ s:(.):$1@:gr/ge'
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s:(.):$1@:gr"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s:(.):$1@:gr"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @OctavioRodriguezPerez: Your Perl is probably ancient (pre-5.14 released before 2011). See the update.

Answer (score 0):

echo "POSA_____POSB" | sed "s/[^_]/&@/g"

or

echo "POSA_____POSB" | sed "s/[POSAB]/&@/g"

Comment: This will place a "@" after each matched character, whether or not it's part of an overall match. For example, `echo "OOPS" | sed "s/[POSAB]/&@/g"` prints "O@O@P@S@".

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
echo "POSA_____POSB" | sed "s/[A-Z]/&@/g"
```

Output:

```
P@O@S@A@_____P@O@S@B@
```

Comment: This will place a "@" after each matched character, whether or not it's part of an overall match. For example, `echo "OOPS" | sed "s/[A-Z]/&@/g"` prints "O@O@P@S@".

Answer (score 0):

You may replace regex pattern using `awk` with `sub` (first matching substring, `sed` "`s///`") or `gsub` (substitute matching substrings globally, `sed` "`s///g`") commands. The regex themselves will not differ between `sed` and `awk`. In your case you want:

#### Solution 1

**EDIT: edited to match the comments**

The following `awk` will limit substitution to a given substring (e.g.'POSA_____POSB'):

```
 echo "OOPS POSA_____POSB" | awk '{str="POSA_____POSB"}; {gsub(/[POSAB]/,"&@",str)}; {gsub(/'POSA_____POSB'/, str); print $0} '
```

If your input consist only of matched string, try this:

```
echo "POSA_____POSB" |  awk '{gsub(/[POSAB]/,"&@");}1'
```

Explanation:

Separate '{}' for each action and explicit `print` are for clarity sake.

The `gsub` accepts 3 arguments `gsub(pattern, substitution [, target])` where target must be variable (`gsub` will change it inplace and store result there).

We use var named 'str' and initialize it with value (your string) before doing any substitutions.

The second `gsub` is there to put modified `str` into `$0` (matches the whole record/line).

The expressions are `greedy` by default --- they will match the longest string possible.

`[]` introduces set of characters to be matched: every occurence of any char will be matched. The expression above says `awk` to match each occurence of any of "POSAB".

Your first regexp does not work as expected for you told `sed` to match `POS` ending in any of `[AB]` (the whole string at once).
In the other expression you told it to match any single character (including "_") when you used: `'.'` (dot).

If you want to generalize this solution you may use: `[\w]` expression which will match any of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` or `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]`, `[0-9]` to match lowercase, uppercase letters and numbers respectively.

#### Solution 2

Note that you might negate character sets with `[^]` so: `[^_]` would also work in this particular case.

Explanation:

Negation means: match anything but the character between '[]'. The '^' character must come as first char, right after opening '['.

#### Sidenotes:

Also it may be good idea to directly indicate you want to match one character at a time with `[POSAB]?` or `[POSAB]{1}`.

Also  note that some implementations of `sed` might need `-r` switch to use extended (more complicated) regexps.

Comment: These will place a "@" after each matched character, whether or not it's part of an overall match. For example, `echo "OOPS" | awk '{gsub(/[POSAB]/,"&@");}1'` prints "O@O@P@S@".

Comment: @GordonDavisson: edited answer to better meet requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The problem is that it must work with any regex, the case "POSA_____POSB" was only an example. A more appropriate example would be:

echo "POSBAAAPOSABBBPOSCPOSB"

that would return this:

P@O@S@B@AAAP@O@S@A@BBBPOSCP@O@S@B@

This is an example, but he regex could contain any character, not just alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

With the given example you can use

```
echo "POSA_____POSB" | sed -r 's/POS([AB])/P@O@S@\1@/g'
```

This will fail for more complicated expressions.
When your input is without `\v` and `\r`, you can use

```
echo "POSA_____POSB" | 
   sed -r 's/POS([AB])/\v&\r/g;  :loop;s/\v([^\r])/\1@\v/;t loop; s/[\v\r]//g'
```